# Dealing with org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: grails

I am getting a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException error, I have an association whit a basic collection types

```
class User {
   String email
   String password
   String role = "user"
   String fullName
   Boolean enabled = false

   Date dateCreated
   Date lastUpdated

   static hasMany = [schools:String]
}
```

I create a view where user can select schools in checkboxs tag, then in a controller action I get schools values and try to apply next query in order to get all users that have some or all selected schools

```
def query = User.where {
    schools in params.list("schools")
}
```

I get following error message

> ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
>   select this_.id as id2_0_, this_.date_created as date2_2_0_, this_.email as email2_0_, this_.user_status as user4_2_0_, this_.full_name as full5_2_0_, this_.last_updated as last6_2_0_, this_.password as password2_0_, this_.user_role as user8_2_0_ from user this_ where this_.id in (?, ?) order by this_.date_created asc [90012-164]

thanks for your time

Comment: What's the content of `params.list("schools")`?

Comment: Hi Sergio, params.list("schools") are values i got from checkboxes with name schools